# ListView checkbox value is false even it is check

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have a checkbox in my listview:

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListViewInfoListTable" runat="server" OnPagePropertiesChanged="ListViewInfoListTable_PagePropertiesChanged" OnSorting="ListViewInfoListTable_Sorting">
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <table id="TableReceiptInfoList" runat="server" class="table table-striped table-hover table-condensed table-bordered">
            <thead>
                <tr id="HeaderRow">
                    <th><asp:CheckBox ID="chkAll" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" Checked="false" OnCheckedChanged="chkAll_CheckedChanged"/></th>
                    <th><asp:LinkButton runat="server" CommandName="sort" CommandArgument="project">Project </asp:LinkButton></th>
                    <th><asp:LinkButton runat="server" CommandName="sort" CommandArgument="date">Date</asp:LinkButton></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr runat="server" id="itemPlaceHolder"></tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </LayoutTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr id="TableRIL">
            <td><asp:CheckBox ID="chk" runat="server" AutoPostBack="false"/></td>
            <td><%# Eval("project_area").ToString() %></td>
            <td><%# Eval("date_packaged").ToString() %></td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

The checkbox even handler checkAll_CheckChnaged is toggling the rows checkbox value:

```
protected void chkAll_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CheckBox chkAll = (CheckBox)sender;
    for (int counter =0; counter < ListViewInfoListTable.Items.Count; counter++)
    {
        if (chkAll.Checked == true)
        {
            ((CheckBox)ListViewInfoListTable.Items[counter].FindControl("chk")).Checked = true;
        }
        else
        {
            ((CheckBox)ListViewInfoListTable.Items[counter].FindControl("chk")).Checked = false;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem I am facing is the checkbox value is showing false even it is checked in the button click:

```
protected void buttonReview_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bool anyCheckBoxChecked = false;
    for (int counter = 0; counter < ListViewInfoListTable.Items.Count; counter++)
    {
        if (((CheckBox)ListViewInfoListTable.Items[counter].FindControl("chk")).Checked == true)
        {
            anyCheckBoxChecked = true;
        }
    }
```

In this line of above code

```
((CheckBox)ListViewInfoListTable.Items[counter].FindControl("chk")).
```

showing checkbox value is false even checkbox is checked. Please help. Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: @Dai, if its not broken, why fix it? Microsoft still supports Webforms, you have a point for greenfield apps, but not everything is green, some of us are stuck working with brownfield apps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not showing data binding code, but I think its safe to assume you are re-binding the data before `buttonReview_Click` is called (which will wipe out all your checked checkboxes).

Make sure you check for `IsPostBack` before binding, for example in your `Page_Load` event:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (IsPostBack)
        return;

    BindListTable();
}
```